# Issue With electron IPC Renderer on event, browser page reloaded

Tags: node.js, electron, ipcrenderer

I am working with electron desktop application using following technologies:
Front end : Angular 8
Communication between main process to child process is IPC Renderer Mechanism.

My issue is - when i am sending message from child to main process, after getting response from main to child the window getting reloaded.How to stop reloading, I am using event.preventDefault() but its not working. I don’t want to reload the page.

Sample code .

In child Process i am calling as :

```
this.es.ipcRenderer.send(‘addGroupmaster’, this.groupForm.value)
```

In mainproces :

```
ipcMain.on(‘addGroupmaster’, (event, args) => {

    group_master.addGroup(args).then((resp) => {
      event.reply('addGroupresponse', resp)
    }).catch((error) => {
      event.reply('addGroupresponse', error)
    });
```

in child process on method getting page was reloaded.
on method is:

```
    this.es.ipcRenderer.on(‘addGroupresponse’, (ev, args) => {
    console.log(args)
    this.nz.run(() => {
    if (args.status == “success”) {
    this.es.remote.dialog.showMessageBox(null, { type: “success”, title: “Success”, message: “Group has been Added successfully” });
    /**********Event to get all items **********/
    this.es.ipcRenderer.send(‘getAllGroups’)
    }
    else {
    this.es.remote.dialog.showMessageBox(null, { type: “error”, title: “Add Failure”, message: args.message });
    }
    })
```

Please help me on this.